# Initial expanded-collapsed state of projects of a groupproject

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

After opening a groupproject, in the `Project Manager` window I see that some projects are expanded and other projects are collapsed.

Each time I open a groupproject, projects and states (expanded/collapsed) are always the same and I didn't understood how I have set them to be expanded or collapsed.

I tried checking the `.groupproj` file but I didn't saw any expanded/collapsed value for the projects.

Where are these informations stored and how to change them?

**Update:**

I've opened the same grouproject from another computer which has Delphi2007 installed. Collapsed and expanded projects are always the same that I can see from my computer. I think these informations are stored somewhere in source files.

Comment: On recent versions of the IDE, upon opening a group project, the active project is expanded, and the other projects are collapsed. I would have assumed that has always been the guess but perhaps not.

Comment: I'm mostly working with D2007. In one groupproj, always the same 2 dprojs are expanded, even if no contained units are opened. No hint in the *.dsk either.

Comment: My D2007 always expands the first project. If the IDE is not closed after the group is closed, it also expands the active project.